# How to convert CSV to HTML table from java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, struts

i'm trying to display a CSV file in HTML form, I decided to use CSVToTable jquery but if there's an easier way to do it please let me know.

I read that i cannot just ask user to pick their file and then render it, i have to first load the file to the server, so I added a jsp page to get the file and i wrote an Struts Action class to get the file.

loadFile.jsp:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="/importAction.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id='fileId' type='file' name='attachmentFile' value='' maxlength='255'/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My importAction Action class:

```
public ActionForward doAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm actionForm,
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    //how do i get the file and output this to the jsp?

    return mapping.findForward("renderCSV"); 
}
```

I also have a target JSP with the following:

renderCSV.jsp:

```
<div id="CSVTable"></div>

<script> 
    $(function() {
        $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv'); 
    });
</script>
```

So the two questions from the above code is:

1) How do I retrieve this file from the JSP in my java class to pass it to the JSP that will render it?

2) In the renderCSV.jsp How do I pass the file I got in my action class into CSVToTable? right now i have 'test.csv' as a placeholder.

I'm open to other sugestions too. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Just create an action that returns data in CSV format, then feed it to javascript where appropriate. Most ppl today use JSON format for these purposes.

Comment: Yes correct, but how do I do that? how would the replacement of the 'test.csv' in the jsp look like? how do I retrieve the attachment in Action and pass it as CSV?

Answer (score 0):

This is sample action `getCSV` that gets the CSV file and output to the response.

```
public ActionForward execute (ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
  File file = new File("C:\\temp\\test.csv");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  //copy binary data to response out
  while(fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1)
    out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
  out.flush();
  fis.close();
  return null;
}
```

So you can use it in your code

```
<div id="CSVTable"></div>

<script> 
    $(function() {
        $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('getCSV.do'); 
    });
</script>
```

For uploading a CSV file read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-file-upload-example/) example.

Comment: Thanks Roman, however this doesn't quite do the trick. The upload of the file i have it in my first post, i can reach the action class with the file, i'm fine up to that point. So I tried your action class but all it does is flush the CSV in one line on a refreshed page. Since you return null the renderCSV.jsp is never called so the jquery and everything in that page is never called, i need to pass it to the CSVToTable. Maybe I'm misunderstanding? are you using the CSVToTable jquery to call the action class? how does getCSV.do get to call an action class if it needs to be on submit button?

Comment: The CSVToTable is using ajax to get data from the action above then parse it and draw a table.

Comment: But ajax can't just trigger a struts action like that so i don't understand how this code works. Right now I have: 1) loadfile.jsp submits the file, this calls the action class. 2) The Action Class calls renderCSV.jsp and should pass the file to it 3) renderCSV.jsp runs the jquery and renders the csv in a table. But from your code it seems the renderCSV.jsp goes first?  then the action class? how is the action class triggered? where is the file upload go? in the same jsp as render csv? then how they they connect?

Comment: You said *ajax can't just trigger a struts action like that*, how ajax can trigger a struts action? 2) without action configuration is unclear how it *renders* and how did you pass the file 3) I know that CVSToTable *loads* data via ajax and you should provide the url for loading data, so the file if you can access that in JSP is useless until you modify the plugin to use inbound javascript array. 3) The action that loads CSV data is a different action and it's called by the plugin when a page is loaded from the browser...

Comment: ... It goes to the server and execute action above that return data in the response. That data is handled by the plugin and modified DOM to insert a table.

Comment: Struts has a config file that holds a mapping. If you look at my orignal post you'll notice the submit in the form has an action, based on this, the config file will look for the action class mapped to this form action, so I don't see how this can be achieved this way. If there is any other suggestion on a different way to do it, i'll take it too.

Comment: What did you try to achieve this way? I don't understand what other suggestion do you want?